# Img file broken when put into a sub folder although the path is correct

Tags: html, image, directory, filepath

[Image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQcm9.png)

My html file is in the uncover pula folder, but the logo is in the images folder.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us the code you use. Normally ```<img src="../Images/Imagename.jpg" />``` should work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.